# svg export in paper.js very slow

Tags: performance, svg, export, paperjs

I'm using `project.exportSVG({asString: true})` with a very large number of paths (thousends). 
This takes very long and sometimes the script will just freeze. 
The `project.exportJSON()` function on the other hand is very fast.

I think this may be because exportSVG creates a DOM node and then makes a string out of it. For I just need the string, something like a lite export that just works with strings would be awesome.
Is there any way to do this?

I use the SVG-string to make a Blob and save it via https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

```
var svg = project.exportSVG({asString: true});
var blob = new Blob([svg], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, 'test.svg');
```

this is a test script I run at http://sketch.paperjs.org

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    new Path.Circle({
        strokeColor: 'red',
        radius: 10,
        position: [i, i]
    });
}


var t_start, t_end;

t_start = new Date().getTime();
project.exportSVG();
t_end = new Date().getTime();
console.log('svg export: ' + (t_end - t_start));

t_start = new Date().getTime();
project.exportJSON();
t_end = new Date().getTime();
console.log('json export: ' + (t_end - t_start));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you, but I can tell you the reason. Take a look at this sketch: [minimal example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/lZFNS8NAEIb/ypBLNzQGvSZ6qiB4UCHipSmyJmO6bboTZqdVCPnv7iYVBSnq7mFm5+OdZ9g+snqHURYVW5RqHSVRRXV4vxKDOmgGA1dwnntzCRfBzucx9KUFfyy+wYOWdbowXLWojuFwnDBtcUEtcQYzxnqWfCVZ12bvMq/3LdiRM2LIZrA0CZjVlBnivLRDacMNNPLsRLMk3kFb5yF8DHnMwHOtBVWcNiiPZue9fOpzh8YXdEwbrCTF945Yiqcb1WtXCBvbZCC8x3HcKH1ariLrqMW0pUbNgu6k5teEOaip+ewTNE7C6DifNvgT6saR/cF6W9zfqf/CjUq/0IWa0Oh//oVRbzsyVlyULVfDBw==) and you can see that export JSON is just the JSON representation of the paper data structures and state while SVG requires a conversion of the output of paper to SVG format. Júrg has done a pretty good job of optimizing the conversion, so while there might be some small incremental gains, it's unlikely that the conversion will ever come close to the raw dump of the paper data structures.